# Qt creator text editor malfunction under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vmware, qt, text-editor, qt-creator

I've upgraded my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 today (clean install) and went through the motions of setting up my development environment. (`apt install build-essential libxcb-xinerama0`, setting up for running 32bit toolchains etc.).

However, after installing Qt creator and opening my project, I quickly realized that the text editor is not behaving like it should.

When scrolling, it often 'duplicates' text up to ten times. Only when marking the text, the display updates and the actual text is displayed.

Since this only occurred after installing Qt Creator on Ubuntu 22.04 (5.15.0-46-generic), I am assuming it is a driver problem or something related.

I am running Ubuntu using VMWare Workstation, the package `openvm-tools-desktop` is installed and up to date, all other packages have been updated as well and, besides the text editor, everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug of QtCreate running on vmware+ubuntu22.04
[Qt BugReport Link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-102844)

You may try

"QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland ~/software/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator"

and run it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Appears to be working. And it's far better to have a 'not so nice' looking window than having a dysfunctional window.